# Как улучшить скрипт сессий?

Tags: php, mysql

Проблема: есть счетчик просмотров страницы, когда заходишь на нее (допустим, на ней до моего захода было 9 просмотров) счетчик обновляется и ставит 10, при следующем обновлении он не обновляется (как и было задумано мной), но есть соц кнопки внизу и, когда нажимаешь опубликовать в моем мире, или фэйсбуке, или твиттере (без разницы), он накручивает счетчик на 1 и сколько раз нажмешь публиковать, на столько он и увеличит.
Проверял id сессии (сессия не меняется). Код предоставляю ниже, может нужно как-то по-другому счетчик написать или вывод информации по-другому сделать, жду развернутого ответа с пояснением, всем спасибо! (заранее).

А вот собственно и код.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<!--Авторизационное меню -->
<? 
session_start();
///////////////////////////////////Файл db.php//////////////////////
$db = mysql_connect("localhost","xxxxx","xxxxxxx");
mysql_select_db("xxxxxxx",$db);              
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {$id = $_GET['id'];}
if (!isset($id)) echo("<script>top.location.href='/';</script>") ; 
?>

<?php 
$result = mysql_query("SELECT title,date,author,view,id,text FROM news WHERE id='$id'",$db);
if (!$result)
{
echo "<p>Запрос из базы данных не прошел!<br> Код ошибки:</p>";
exit (mysql_error());
}
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
$myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result);
if(!isset($_SESSION['view'][$id])){
$views=$myrow['view'];
$views++;
mysql_query ("UPDATE news SET view = ".$views." WHERE id='".$id."'");
$_SESSION['view'][$id] = $id;
}
else{
if(isset($_SESSION['view'][$id])){
$views=$myrow['view'];
$_SESSION['view'][$id] = $id;
}
}
}
else
{
echo "<p>Информация не может быть извлечена</p>";
exit();
}
printf ("<table style='border-radius:10px; border:0px solid #f2efef;' border='0' align='center' class='knews'>
<tr class='news_title_head'><td>
<div class='news_name'><span class='link_big'>%s</span></div>
<div class='post-date'>
<p class='news_adds'>Дата добавления: %s</p>
</div>
<div class='head_info'>
<p class='author_adds alignleft'>Автор: <b>%s</b> |<span  style='margin-left:10px;'>%s просмотров</span></p>
</td></tr><tr><td><table border='0'><tr>
<td valign='top' style='text-align:justify; color:gray;'><div style='margin-top:-10px;'>%s</div></p></td></tr></table>
</div>
</td></tr>
<tr><td></td></tr>
<tr><td style='padding-top:10px;'>
<!-- AddThis Button BEGIN -->
<div class='addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style addthis_32x32_style'>
<a class='addthis_button_preferred_1'></a>
<a class='addthis_button_preferred_2'></a>
<a class='addthis_button_preferred_3'></a>
<a class='addthis_button_preferred_4'></a>
<a class='addthis_button_compact'></a>
<a class='addthis_counter addthis_bubble_style'></a>
</div>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://s7.addthis.com/js/250/addthis_widget.js#pubid=xa-4f3b99ef2aa35c0f'></script>
<!-- AddThis Button END --><div style='width:697px; height:1px; background:transparent url(images/dot.gif) repeat-x left bottom; padding-top:5px;'></div>
</td></tr>
</table>
",$myrow['title'],$myrow['date'],$myrow['author'],$myrow['view'],$myrow['text'],$myrow['id'],$myrow['title']);
print_r($_SESSION);echo session_id();
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Как улучшить ? Выкинуть и переписать всё по новой, и не использовать html в php

Comment: не знаю я готов все сделать чтоб эту проблему устранить а как без html без него не обойтись)))

Answer (score 2):

В таблицу news добавляем поле view_count типа Int 11.
Далее вставляем, например, такой код:

```
if($_COOKIE['news']!=$id)
{
setcookie ("news", $id, time()+3600*48);
mysql_query("UPDATE `news` SET `view_count`=`view_count`+1 WHERE `id`='$id'");
}
```

Логика следующая, если юзер открыл новость, и у него нет печеньки с id новости, то счётчик просмотров новости обновляем на 1 и откладываем ему печеньку с id новости, и при любых действиях на странице счётчик не обновится. Если я правильно понял задачу.

Comment: собственно так у меня тоже сделано на блоге. 6 часов срок годности выпечки :)

Comment: Shrek у тебя такая же проблема как и у меня))) заходил на твой блог проверял все тоже самое

Comment: ваш ответ не работает

Comment: Значит что ты вы делаете не правильно